# How to straighten a tilted face after cropping?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, face-detection, cascade-classifier

I'm doing a project on facial feature extraction. I have written MATLAB code for histogram equalization, face detection and face cropping. Now I want to straighten the face if it is tilted. Can you help me with the MATLAB code? Here is the code I have written so far.

```
clear all
clc

I=imread('100_3082.jpg');
figure(1)
imshow(I);
J=rgb2gray(I);
figure(2)
imshow(J);                                                             
P = histeq(J);
figure(3)
imshow(P);

FDetect = vision.CascadeObjectDetector;

BB = step(FDetect,P);
hold on
for i = 1:size(BB,1)
rectangle('Position',BB(i,:),'LineWidth',5,'LineStyle','-','EdgeColor','r');

end
for i = 1:size(BB,1)
Q= imcrop(P,BB(i,:));
figure(4)
imshow(Q);
end
title('Face Detection');   

hold off;
```

This is the image (*'100_3082.jpg'*) I'm working on:-

[image: 100_3082.jpg]

Comment: Please show an example face image so we can properly run the code on our end.  Specifically, please upload `100_3082.jpg`.

Comment: @rayryeng i have attached the image 100_3082.jpg

Comment: Didn't you mean to write `img` instead of `I` here: `I=imread('100_3082.jpg');`

Comment: yes...you are right...done the correction. @Sardar_Usama

Comment: you need to locate facial features: eyes, nose, mouth so you can align the face to a "canonical" pose.

Comment: thanks @Shai I will try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Algorithm:-**

 My solution implements your task using the following algorithm:

**1.** Finding the position of both eyes.
 
**2.** Finding the angle between them.
 
**3.** Rotating the image based on that angle.

**Input Image:-**

 Input image of this code is the one you're getting at the end of your code i.e. `Q`.

[image: input]

**Code:-**

```
% Dividing the image in two halves for better detection
% To see why , see this: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/155126-how-does-the-vision-cascadeobjectdetector-detect-left-and-right-eyes-separately-it-is-constantly-de
n = fix(size(Q,2)/2);
lefthalf = Q(:,1:n,:);
righthalf = Q(:,n+1:end,:);

RightEyeDetect = vision.CascadeObjectDetector('RightEyeCART');
LeftEyeDetect = vision.CascadeObjectDetector('LeftEyeCART');
% vision.CascadeObjectDetector(EyePairBig) is not much efficient in this case
% because the image is tilted. So, detecting both eyes separately.

%Bounding Boxes
BBREye= step(RightEyeDetect,lefthalf); %Right eye is on our left
BBLEye= step(LeftEyeDetect,righthalf); %Left eye is on our right
BBLEye(1)=BBLEye(1)+n; %correcting the x position of left eye (caused due to dividing the image in two halves)

figure
imshow(imrotate(Q,(180/pi)*atan((BBREye(2)-BBLEye(2))/(BBREye(1)-BBLEye(1)))));
```

**Output:-**

[image: Output]

---

**P.S:** 

**1.** This may not be a perfect solution.

**2.** It is assumed that there is only one tilted face to be corrected. 

**3.** The accuracy of this solution is dependent on the accuracy of detection of eyes for which the built-in MATLAB functions, which are based on *Viola-Jones Algorithm*, are used. 

**4.** In case if this code fails, you can check whether the eyes were correctly detected or not by adding these lines:

```
BBEyes= [BBLEye ; BBREye];
figure,
imshow(Q); 
for i = 1:size(BBEyes,1)
 rectangle('Position',BBEyes(i,:),'LineWidth',4,'LineStyle','-','EdgeColor','r');
end
```

For your image, since this worked, you can still check whether the eyes were correctly detected or not. The result is the following which is correct:-

[image: eyes detection]

Comment: This is perfect. I thought that there is a built-in function to do this. but thanks! This is something new for me. I will study the code now. :)

Comment: can you explain this line?  'BBLEye(1)=BBLEye(1)+n;' What does that 1 indicate? If I run the same code for any other image it gives me this error  _Attempted to access BBLEye(1); index out of bounds because numel(BBLEye)=0_

Comment: @Emma I've already explained that line in the comments! since i divided the image in two parts, therefore the x-coordinate of the right half will start from 0 but it actually should start from some other value depending on the last value of the left half of the image!! `1` is indicating the first term of `BBLEye` which is x-coordinate. Regarding the error, I already mentioned that it is dependent on the accuracy of eye-detection! No detection or wrong detection will lead to errors/incorrect results. But if you detect the face correctly,  it is most likely that it will work